# From a physics textbook: how did they get the eccentric anomaly ψ?

Tags: taylor-expansion, circles, conic-sections

The initial formula was:
$$
\begin{align}
\cos\psi &= \cos(θ-θ₀) + e \sin^2(θ-θ₀) - e^2 \cos(θ-θ₀)\sin^2(θ-θ₀)\\
&+ e^3 \cos^2(θ-θ₀)\sin^2(θ-θ₀) - ...\\
\end{align}
$$
Where e is the eccentricity, $ψ$ is the eccentric anomaly, and $θ-θ₀$ is the true anomaly.
They got out of this:
$$
\psi = (θ-θ₀) - e \sin(θ-θ₀) + {e^2\over4} \sin2(θ-θ₀)+ \dots
$$
I've tried various things with taylor series, but got nowhere, does anyone here know how this was derived?

Comment: To improve your post, use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for the mathematics formulas. As written, those formulas are difficult to read.

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem, or not? Please give a feedback.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an expansion up to $e^2$ you can set
$$
\psi=\psi_0+e \alpha+e^2\beta+O(e^3),
$$
where $\psi_0=\theta-\theta_0$, while $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are unknown coefficients to be found.
Using [trig addition formulas](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometricAdditionFormulas.html)
and Taylor series for sine and cosine
we can then write:
$$
\begin{align}
\cos\psi &=\cos(\psi_0+e \alpha+e^2\beta+O(e^3))\\
&=\cos\psi_0\cos(e \alpha+e^2\beta+O(e^3))-\sin\psi_0\sin(e \alpha+e^2\beta+O(e^3))\\
&=\cos\psi_0\left(1-{1\over2}e^2\alpha^2\right)-\sin\psi_0(e \alpha+e^2\beta)+O(e^3)\\
&=\cos\psi_0-e\alpha\sin\psi_0-e^2\left({1\over2}\alpha^2\cos\psi_0
+\beta\sin\psi_0\right)+O(e^3)\\
\end{align}
$$
Comparing this with the given expansion we thus obtain:
$$
\begin{align}
-\alpha\sin\psi_0 &=\sin^2\psi_0\\
{1\over2}\alpha^2\cos\psi_0+\beta\sin\psi_0 &=\cos\psi_0\sin^2\psi_0
\end{align}
$$
which can be solved to get
$$
\alpha=-\sin\psi_0,\quad
\beta={1\over2}\cos\psi_0\sin\psi_0={1\over4}\sin2\psi_0
$$
If desired, the same method can be used to find the expansion up to $e^3$ terms.